# CHARINDEX - pick days out of nvarchar

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to add 'days' to the below code. The string is along the lines of

- 1 days 3 hrs 4 min 15 sec
- 23 hrs 3 min 4 sec
- 4 min 1 sec
- 4 hrs 3 min 1 sec
- 5 days 3 hrs 1 min 0 sec

Every time I try something I think will work, it errors on something else. The below code works. I just need to add 'days' to it.

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('hrs',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0 
            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0,CHARINDEX('hrs',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0))
            ELSE 0 END AS Hrs,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('hrs',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0  AND CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0
            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),CHARINDEX('hrs',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0)+3,CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) - CHARINDEX('hrs',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0)-3)
         WHEN CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0
            THEN  SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0,CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0))
        ELSE 0 END AS mins,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0  AND CHARINDEX('sec',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0
            THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0)+3,CHARINDEX('sec',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) - CHARINDEX('min',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0)-3)
         WHEN CHARINDEX('sec',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0) >0
            THEN  SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0,CHARINDEX('sec',REPLACE([Session Duration],' ',''),0))
        ELSE 0 END AS secs
FROM table1
```

Comment: Simplify the problem! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Just debug it, comment all other columns and select just one column a time, correct that column code to get no more error, then go next to another columns. By the way, could you provide sample data of your `table1`?

Comment: If you use SQL server 2006+ I would suggest simplying the existing SQL into using string_split and use Windows functions lag or lead to get the correct values to change and use XML for path to concat the records into a string again

Comment: Removed excess code, example of relative data already in post.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will return the `Days`, if there is no `days` in the `Session Duration` string it will return 0.

```
SELECT ...,
       ...,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('days', REPLACE([Session Duration], ' ', ''), 0) > 0 
       THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE([Session Duration], ' ', ''), 0, CHARINDEX('days', REPLACE([Session Duration], ' ', ''), 0))
       ELSE 0 END AS [Days],
      ...
FROM Table1
```

Comment: That's what I've tried, but I get 
'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1days11' to data type int.'

Comment: In the example, there is a space between `1` and `days`. Is your string as `1days11hrs` ?

Comment: The data is as per the example 1 days. But the error is as per the comment 1days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best answer but I did it like this:

```
declare @table table (data nvarchar(30))
insert into @table 
values
('1 sec'),
('4 min 1 sec'),
('4 hrs 3 min 1 sec'),
('23 hrs 3 min 4 sec'),
('1 days 3 hrs 4 min 15 sec'),
('1 days 23 hrs 59 min 59 sec'),
('5 days 3 hrs 1 min 0 sec'),
('532 days 3 hrs 1 min 0 sec')

select 
    data,
    CONVERT(int,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(data, PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] sec', data),PATINDEX('% sec', data)-PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] sec', data)+1))) secs,  
    CONVERT(int,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(data, PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] min%', data),PATINDEX('% min%', data)-PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] min%', data)+1))) mins,
    CONVERT(int,LTRIM(SUBSTRING(data, PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] hrs%', data),PATINDEX('% hrs%', data)-PATINDEX('%[ 0-9][0-9] hrs%', data)+1))) hrs,
    CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(data, 0,PATINDEX('% days%', data))) days
from
    @table
```

Output:

[image]

Honestly though, my main advice would be not to store this information like that in the first place and try to split the values out into separate columns before inserting them into the database table. If you do that, processing the table will be faster and it will also take up less disk space because integers take way less space than strings.